# How can I jump between hanging ladders?

Tags: vessel

I try to jump between distant hanging ladders, but can't make it! This is frustrating :(

Comment: Can you provide any more details? Level, or a screenshot maybe?

Comment: Don't try to jump from the top of the ladder, you'll bounce off the ceiling and get no distance. Also, make sure to be holding (up) as you reach the destination ladder so that you grab it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get as high as possible without your jump causing you to hit the roof.

Also you can unlock the nozzle which pushes you back and use it to jump and hover across to the other ladders